# SQL query SELECT FROM [value from column of another table]

Tags: sql-server, select, inner-join, dynamic-sql

I have a table X where a trigger will insert a row when there's a changes to some tables. I've inserted the table name into table X.

Now, I would like to `select` the data from table X while `inner join` with the actual table itself. Is it possible by using a value from a column of the select table as the table for inner join?

The query should looks something like this

```
SELECT X.a, Y.b, Y.c FROM X
INNER JOIN [X.TableName] AS Y ON Y.ID = X.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Executing

```
select 'SELECT X.a, Y.b, Y.c FROM X
INNER JOIN [' + X.TableName + '] AS Y ON X.ID = Y.ID 
where x.primarykey =' + x.primarykey from x
```

Will output a series of sql statements like

```
SELECT X.a, Y.b, Y.c FROM X
INNER JOIN [ customer ] AS Y ON X.ID = Y.ID
where x.primarykey = 1234
```

that you can then execute "sql to build sql" if you will.

Comment: @Martin probably yes, but its just a utility query

Comment: The first query is incomplete, and the resulting queries will join all records in X against all tables used in any of the records, not against the table specified for each record.

Comment: @Guffa you are correct, I added the from clause.  You are wrong on your second point however.  It will generate a select statement for each row in x, within that select it will be joining the table specified in that row.

Comment: @Gratzy: You are mistaken. Look at the generated query. It has nothing that limits it to a single record from the X table, so it will join all records in X against the table, regardless of which table the records specify.

Comment: @Guffa presumably x looks something like tablename,id,a,b,c,d where tablename is the table that the row came from and id is the id in that table.  Therefore joining on the "tablename" where x.id = tablename.id will yield you the row you are looking for.

Comment: @Guffa I think I understand actually what your saying I suppose I can modify it to have a where clause like where x.tablename = tablename

Comment: @faulty - A function that takes a string containing an object name and escapes it properly. e.g. `select quotename('foo]bar')` gives `[foo]]bar]`

Comment: When I do this `exec(select 'SELECT X.a, Y.b, Y.c FROM X
INNER JOIN [' + X.TableName + '] AS Y ON X.ID = Y.ID 
where x.primarykey =' + x.primarykey from x)` I get error near `select` and `)`. Do I have to escape another level of quote?

Comment: I tried `exec('select ''SELECT X.a, Y.b, Y.c FROM X INNER JOIN ['' + X.TableName + ''] AS Y ON X.ID = Y.ID where x.primarykey ='' + x.primarykey from x')`. It's merely generating a list of sql

Comment: @faulty: As the select returns a list of queries, you have to take each query an execute it manually. Or create a cursor for it, so that you can loop through the result and execute each query.

Comment: 'primarykey' is supposed to be the primary key of the table, not a literal and its not exec('select etc. If your using query analyzer just select 'select ...  this will generate the sql satements.

Comment: @Guffa: I've no problem generating the list. Do you mind to show me how to use a cursor in your answer? I'm planning to put this into a VIEW so it can be access easily. Thank

Comment: @faulty: You can't use a cursor in a view.

Comment: @Guffa: Bummer, how about SP?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. You can't use values as table names directly in a query, and you can't join each record against a different table.

You would have to make the join for a single record, and create the query dynamically to use a value as table name:

```
declare @name varchar(50)
set @name = select TableName from X where ID = 42
exec('select X.a, Y.b, Y.c from X innner join ' + @name + ' as Y on Y.DI = X.ID where X.ID = 42')
```

Comment: @Martin: Well, it's questionable if this method should be used at all... A database layout shouldn't force you to use dynamically created queries.

Comment: Not sure how that answers the point I made. You supplied the answer!

Comment: @faulty: Yes. You can only get a single result at a time, as each result joins on a different table.

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @table AS NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

-- of course you'll have to add your WHERE clause here 
SELECT @table = TableName FROM X;
SET @sql = 'SELECT X.a, Y.b, Y.c FROM X INNER JOIN '+@table+' AS Y ON Y.ID = X.ID';

EXEC(@sql);
```