# Using the result of a query as a table name

Tags: sql, sqlite

If we have table A as follows:

```
+-------+
+ Table +
+-------+
```

How would one perform a query involving values of `A.table` as the table name?

What I mean is something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT "Table" as "tbl" FROM "A";
SELECT * FROM "tbl";
```

but in one statement.

Comment: It would help if you could provide why the sample you provided isn't working for you. For instance, is it causing an error (and what's the error message)?

Comment: @JohnM.Wright I need this as one statement

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5668044/682840
I don't believe it's possible to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has no built-in mechanism to construct SQL statements dynamically; this is not possible.

(There is the `eval` extension, but it is not part of the default distribution.)