# How to select data from multiple tables where table name is value from a column of another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table consists of table name, for example:

TableA

```
    UID  TableName  CifKey  ...
    1     xxx       12345
    1     yyy       12345
    1     xxx       12345
    2     zzz       45678
```

How can I select data from tables that having name same as the `TableName` column in Table A?

For example:

```
SELECT A.a, B.b 
FROM TableA A 
JOIN ' + @TableName + ' B ON A.Cifkey = B.Cifkey 
WHERE A.uid = @uid AND A.cifkey = @cifkey
```

Thank you!

Comment: If `uid = 1` and `Cifkey = 12345`, what would be the TableName?

Comment: tablename will be xxx and yyy, thanks!

Comment: what is the primary key of Table A ?

Comment: your table info details are flawed,there is no way you can pass two tables that to with same name when uid=1 and cifkey=12345,i don't see any reason as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is the way to go:

```
DECLARE @uid    INT = 1,
        @cifkey INT = 12345

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'SELECT
    A.a, B.b -- Replace with correct column names
FROM TableA A
JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(TableName) + ' B
    ON A.Cifkey = B.Cifkey
WHERE
    A.uid = @uid 
    AND A.cifkey = @cifkey
UNION ALL
'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TableName FROM TableA WHERE UID = @uid AND cifkey = @cifkey
) t

IF @sql <> '' BEGIN
    -- Remove the last UNION ALL
    SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 11)

    PRINT @sql

    EXEC sp_executesql
        @sql,
        N'@uid INT, @cifkey INT',
        @uid,
        @cifkey
END
```

Comment: This is the solution I want! Thank you so much! Thanks guys :)

Comment: When dynamic SQL is the only solution you often have a database modelling issue

Comment: Generally, but not always. Dynamic SQL has its use, catch-all queries for one.

Comment: Very much true. Totally agreed with @Nick.McDermaid

Answer (score 0):

If your join works,dynamic sql is the way you want to accomplish the task..

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(100)
select @tablename=tablename from yourtable where uid=@uid and cifkey=@cifkey

declare @sqlquery nvarchar(4000)
set @sqlquery='SELECT A.a, B.b FROM TableA A 
JOIN ' + @TableName + ' B 
ON A.Cifkey = B.Cifkey 
WHERE A.uid = @uid and A.cifkey = @cifkey';

exec sp_executesql @sqlquery,
N'@uid int,@cifkey int',
@uid=10,@cifkey=100
```

Comment: hi, but it would be multiple tables, for example when `@uid = 1` and `@cifkey = 12345`, then i need to select data from table xxx and table yyy.

Comment: hi, `select @tablename=tablename from yourtable where uid=@uid and cifkey=@cifkey` like this I only can get the table xxx, cannot get table yyy. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a dyanmic query - something like this

```
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @uid INT = 1
DECLARE @cifkey INT = 12345
SELECT @tablename = TableName FROM TableA WHERE uid = @uid AND cifkey = @cifkey

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(500)

SELECT @query = 'select A.a, B.b from TableA A JOIN ' + @tablename + ' B 
ON A.Cifkey = B.Cifkey 
WHERE A.uid = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@uid) + ' and A.cifkey = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @cifkey)

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: hi, `SELECT @tablename = TableName FROM TableA WHERE uid = @uid AND cifkey = @cifkey` like this I only can get the table xxx, cannot get table yyy. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, not as you are asking. You can, however, use dynamic SQL as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668070/1736312) to create a series of `SELECT` statements that could be merged with `UNION`s to produce your desired results, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'SELECT A.a, B.b FROM TableA A 
        JOIN ' + TableName + ' B 
        ON A.Cifkey = B.Cifkey 
        WHERE A.uid = @uid and A.cifkey = @cifkey
        UNION
        '
FROM TableA
```

Just copy the results into the SQL editor, remove the `UNION` from the last item, and run the whole thing to get your results.

Answer (score 0):

i have to say... this is a bit crazy

Note :  I added a ID column to TableA as a primary key. This is required to uniquely identity the rows to differenciate multiple rows with same UID & Cifkey

```
-- Create the table
create table TableA
(
    ID      int identity,
    UID     int,
    TableName   varchar(5),
    CifKey      int,
    a       int
)

create table xxx
(
    CifKey      int,
    b       int
)

create table yyy
(
    CifKey      int,
    b       int
)

create table zzz
(
    CifKey      int,
    b       int
)

set nocount on

-- Insert some sample data
insert into TableA select 1, 'xxx', 12345, 1
insert into TableA select 1, 'yyy', 12345, 2
insert into TableA select 1, 'xxx', 12345, 3
insert into TableA select 2, 'zzz', 45678, 4

insert into xxx select 12345, 100
insert into yyy select 12345, 200
insert into zzz select 45678, 300

-- the Dynamic SQL query
declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

select  @sql    = N'SELECT A.a, b = COALESCE('

select  @sql    = @sql +
        + N'B' + convert(varchar(10), ID) + '.b,'
from    TableA
order by ID

select  @sql    = left(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ')' + char(13)

select  @sql    = @sql 
        + N'FROM TableA A'  + char(13)

; with cte as
(
    select  *, rn = convert(varchar(10), ID)
    from    TableA
)
select  @sql    = @sql 
        + N'LEFT JOIN ' + quotename(TableName) + ' AS B' + rn + ' ' + char(13)
        + N'ON  A.CifKey    = B' + rn + '.CifKey' + char(13)
        + N'AND A.ID        = ' + rn + char(13)
from    cte

print   @sql 
exec    sp_executesql @sql

set nocount off

-- clean up 
drop table TableA
drop table xxx
drop table yyy
drop table zzz

-- The generated Query (print @sql)
SELECT A.a, b = COALESCE(B1.b,B2.b,B3.b,B4.b)
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN [xxx] AS B1 
ON  A.CifKey    = B1.CifKey
AND A.ID        = 1
LEFT JOIN [yyy] AS B2 
ON  A.CifKey    = B2.CifKey
AND A.ID        = 2
LEFT JOIN [xxx] AS B3 
ON  A.CifKey    = B3.CifKey
AND A.ID        = 3
LEFT JOIN [zzz] AS B4 
ON  A.CifKey    = B4.CifKey
AND A.ID        = 4
```